# Trying to make regex JSLint compliant

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, jslint

I'm trying to make this regex:

```
var url_pattern = /(\()((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(\))|(\[)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(\])|(\{)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(\})|(<|&(?:lt|#60|#x3c);)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(>|&(?:gt|#62|#x3e);)|((?:^|[^=\s'"\]])\s*['"]?|[^=\s]\s+)(\b(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+(?:(?!&(?:gt|#0*62|#x0*3e);|&(?:amp|apos|quot|#0*3[49]|#x0*2[27]);[.!&',:?;]?(?:[^a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]|$))&[a-z0-9\-._~!$'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]*)*[a-z0-9\-_~$()*+=\/#[\]@%])/img;
```

JSLint compliant. It's complaining about the use of . and not escaping [ and ].

(Source: http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/linkifyurl/linkify.html)

edit: Not that big of a deal, I just did it in the backend anyway. I'd still like a version (since I'm building a rendering engine-y thing, but this isn't super urgent anymore).

Comment: while JSLint is correct about some of your issues, it is not required to follow its advice to the letter -- it doesn't always know best.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var url_pattern = /(\()((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(\))|(\[)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(\])|(\{)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(\})|(<|&(?:lt|#60|#x3c);)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(>|&(?:gt|#62|#x3e);)|((?:^|[^=\s'"\]])\s*['"]?|[^=\s]\s+)(\b(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+(?:(?!&(?:gt|#0*62|#x0*3e);|&(?:amp|apos|quot|#0*3[49]|#x0*2[27]);[.!&',:?;]?(?:[^a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]|$))&[a-z0-9\-._~!$'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]*)*[a-z0-9\-_~$()*+=\/#[\]@%])/img;
```

with

```
var url_pattern = new RegExp("([\\.+])", "img"); // simplified for my sanity
```

With the string properly escaped, `\` to `\\`

---

EDIT:

```
var a = new RegExp("(\\()((?:ht|f)tps?:\\/\\/[a-z0-9\\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\\/?#[\\]@%]+)(\\))|(\\[)((?:ht|f)tps?:\\/\\/[a-z0-9\\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\\/?#[\\]@%]+)(\\])|(\\{)((?:ht|f)tps?:\\/\\/[a-z0-9\\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\\/?#[\\]@%]+)(\\})|(<|&(?:lt|#60|#x3c);)((?:ht|f)tps?:\\/\\/[a-z0-9\\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\\/?#[\\]@%]+)(>|&(?:gt|#62|#x3e);)|((?:^|[^=\\s'\"\\]])\\s*['\"]?|[^=\\s]\\s+)(\\b(?:ht|f)tps?:\\/\\/[a-z0-9\\-._~!$'()*+,;=:\\/?#[\\]@%]+(?:(?!&(?:gt|#0*62|#x0*3e);|&(?:amp|apos|quot|#0*3[49]|#x0*2[27]);[.!&',:?;]?(?:[^a-z0-9\\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\\/?#[\\]@%]|$))&[a-z0-9\\-._~!$'()*+,;=:\\/?#[\\]@%]*)*[a-z0-9\\-_~$()*+=\\/#[\\]@%])", "gim");
```

The above passes jslint

Comment: That unfortunately does not solve the problem. It still complains that [ and ] are 'unescaped'

Comment: @user798080 did you do `new RegExp(..)`? ..or just copy the regex?

Comment: I don’t understand this answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with escaped `[` characters:
`var url_pattern = /(\()((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#\[\]@%]+)(\))|(\[)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#\[\]@%]+)(\])|(\{)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#\[\]@%]+)(\})|(<|&(?:lt|#60|#x3c);)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#\[\]@%]+)(>|&(?:gt|#62|#x3e);)|((?:^|[^=\s'"\]])\s*['"]?|[^=\s]\s+)(\b(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$'()*+,;=:\/?#\[\]@%]+(?:(?!&(?:gt|#0*62|#x0*3e);|&(?:amp|apos|quot|#0*3[49]|#x0*2[27]);[.!&',:?;]?(?:[^a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#\[\]@%]|$))&[a-z0-9\-._~!$'()*+,;=:\/?#\[\]@%]*)*[a-z0-9\-_~$()*+=\/#\[\]@%])/img;`

It still complains about "insecure `^`", which is difficult to fix because it’s essentially implying that you should write out all the characters you *want* to match instead of listing the ones you don’t want to match. Which of course defeats the purpose of `^`. So you can ignore this warning.

Comment: This didn't work with "www.google.com" or "google.com" whereas the original did.

Comment: Neither this one nor the original matches `google.com`. The both match `http://google.com`.